# Поддерживаемые устройства в Google Play

Tags: google-play

В Google Play не очень доходчиво указан список поддерживаемых устройств. Например, в списке есть:
Samung
Galaxy Tab 2 7.0 WiFi
Не особенно ясно... Поддерживается ли, например, устройство "samsung galaxy tab 2 7.0 P3100"?

Answer (score 1):

Ваш планшет относится к линейке GT-2. Их там несколько штук, и различаются они наличием коммуникационных модулей (3G, EDGE, HSDMA и т.п.). Поэтому можете смело качать себе из Google Play.

Обычно проблемами неподдерживаемых устройств страдают китайские планшеты. У Самсунга таких проблем нет.